# C++ Segmentation Fault From Null Pointer Solution?

Tags: c++

I'm getting a segmentation fault on this program, and I know it has something to do with a null pointer being dereferenced, but I'm not exactly sure which one is causing the error. I'm just not certain as to how to fix the error while maintaining the purpose of the original program - it will compile, but at runtime I get the segfault I was just talking about.

main:

```
#include "link.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
 link * head_pointer = new link(NULL, NULL) ;
 for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
 string new_string;
 getline(cin, new_string);
 string* pointer_to_input = new string(new_string);
 link * current_link = new link(head_pointer, pointer_to_input );
 head_pointer = current_link;
}

 head_pointer -> printAll(*head_pointer);
 return 42;
}
```

link:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include "link.h"
using namespace std;
link::link(link * pointer_to_link, string * pointer_to_string)
{
  next = pointer_to_link;
  value = pointer_to_string;
}
link::~link() {
 delete value;
 delete next;
}
link * link::getNext() {
 return next;
}
string * link::getString() {
 return value;
}
int link::printAll(link link_to_print)  {
 cout << *link_to_print.getString() << endl;
 if (link_to_print.next != NULL) {
 return  printAll(*link_to_print.getNext());
} else {
 return 0;
}
}
```

Comment: Use fewer pointers, specifically less dynamic allocation. There's no need for all that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your destructor does look like an error, you shouldn't delete in destructor if you didn't allocate that in constructor:

```
link::~link() {
}
```

You should post your link.h to get more detailed explanation.

Without `link.h` it's not clear what else is wrong, however, there are also other problems:

- `link::printAll looks` like a static method and should be called as: link::printAll(head_pointer);
- you `printAll` should take by pointer, otherwise it it will create a copy of your link and delete it.
- `printAll` has multiple issues as well. Probably it should have been something as follows:

---

```
void link::printAll(link *link_to_print)
{
    if (!link_to_print)
        return;
    if (link_to_print->getString())
        cout << *link_to_print->getString() << endl;
    printAll(link_to_print->next);
}
```

and your main:

```
int main()
{
    link * head_pointer = new link(NULL, NULL);
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        string new_string = str;
        getline(cin, new_string);
        string* pointer_to_input = new string(new_string);
        link * current_link = new link(head_pointer, pointer_to_input);
        head_pointer = current_link;
    }

    link::printAll(head_pointer);
    return 42;
}
```

In short to avoid errors you shouldn't store pointers to strings in your link, you should just store strings themselves. Your links perhaps shouldn't assume ownership of other links:

```
struct link
{
    link *next;
    string value;

    link(link *next, const std::string& value) : next(next), value(value) {}

    link * getNext();
    const std::string& getString() const;
    static void printAll(link *link_to_print);
};

link * link::getNext() {
    return next;
}
const string& link::getString() const {
    return value;
}
void link::printAll(link *link_to_print)
{
    if (!link_to_print)
        return;
    cout << link_to_print->getString() << endl;
    printAll(link_to_print->next);
}
```

and your main:

```
int main()
{
    link * head_pointer = new link(NULL, "");
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        string new_string;
        getline(cin, new_string);
        link * current_link = new link(head_pointer, new_string);
        head_pointer = current_link;
    }

    link::printAll(head_pointer);

    // TODO: now you need to walk head_pointer and delete all links manually.
    return 42;
}
```

Once you learn how memory management works in general you should most likely redesign your link using some kind of smart pointer helper class, such as [unique_ptr](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr) or [shared_ptr](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr). And off course, once you master linked list you should start using [std::list](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list).

Comment: That did the trick... Wow I had no idea that that could cause a Segmentation Fault, I thought the error would be something about dereferencing...thanks

Comment: "you shouldn't delete in destructor if you didn't allocate that in constructor" is a terrible rule.  If an object takes ownership of constructor arguments, like `std::unique_ptr` does, then it is perfectly normal for its destructor to free them.

Comment: @BenVoigt if ctor takes onwnership then copy constructor and assignment operators have to be defined (or deleted). In any case, without link.h it's difficult to tell, but overall looks like this code should be revisited.

Comment: @BenVoigt where is the infinite recursion?

Comment: @Pavel: Yes, that's the real rule, commonly called the "Rule of Three" (and became "Rule of Five" since C++11, since there are also move constructor and move assignment to worry about)

Comment: Sorry I just saw there was no conditional on the recursive call, but there is an early exit so the recursion is bounded.

Answer (score 1):

`link::printAll` takes its argument by value, which has two important effects:

1. The argument inside the function is a second link object created by making copies of the same `value` and `next` pointer.
2. The copy has automatic storage duration and is destroyed at the end of the function call.

Therefore, you have double frees going on.  In particular, both the copy made in the recursive call and the sub-`link` of the original `link` share the same `value` pointer, and both try to delete it.  The second deletion causes undefined behavior.

The solution is to respect the rule-of-three and not allow shallow copies of raw pointers.  There are two possible approaches for managing objects owned by pointer:

- Write a copy constructor to go with your destructor, so the two deletes mentioned above act on two different copies of the value.

OR

- Use a smart pointer, such as `std::shared_ptr`, so you don't have to write a destructor by hand at all.

Note that you *need* a pointer to implement the connection between objects in the linked list, but you do not need a pointer to store the data.  Having a data member of type `std::string`, instead of `std::string *`, would be just fine and do the right thing when copied (It makes sense to think of `std::string` as a smart pointer to an array of characters, that just happens to also have some extra string-manipulation functions tacked on).

Comment: I agree in general, but IMO shared_ptr is a heavy weight thing that I'd rather try to avoid it; Thought, it would make things easy for a simple list attempt.